# problem with localhost | net::err_empty_response

Tags: connection, localhost

I have a MERN app where I use REST API to communicate with DB, I can not send API requests when I'm in localhost but f.e. GET method to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts works fine as well as on production. When I checked out this project on other laptop it works. In my laptop after making login request i'm getting this:

post http://localhost:3000/login net::err_empty_response

Answer (score 0):

In my .env i didn't write 
MONGODB_LOCAL=mongodb+srv://yourname:@cluster0.qbasi.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority